# After editing JComboBox the item list opens under another JComboBox cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

[Attached image for reference][1]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: I guess the JComboBox focus event is not fetching the current cell in focus.
Also I will have to add editors to each instance of JComboBox more appropriately.
Could anyone help me correct the code above.

Comment: Why did the edit not include an MRE / SSCCE? *"Could anyone help me correct the code above."* Can you follow tips designed to ***help us*** to help you?

Comment: Can that code be copy/pasted into an IDE, compiled without any change, and run to see the problem? Try it yourself.

Comment: Its pretty clear that this code was run in an IDE hence attached the output as attachement above. (showing where the problem is occurring)

Comment: *"showing where the problem is occurring"* No [mre] - I have better things to do. Don't forget. It is you, and you alone, who has an interest in solving this problem, for everybody else it is purely academic and there are lots of other people who need help.

Comment: I'll look into this myself. I've provided all the input from my end.This is going nowhere. Thanks